# Transformation in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a problem, I have a Pattern image composed by circles. So I find circles with cv::findContours function, but the problem is to order these circles. I attach te pattern image:
[image]

So now I want to order the points in rows from left to right and from the last bottom row to the top. The problem is that some points that belong to different rows, have the same Y and so I can't order them. With gimp I tried to "rectify" the image to obtain points belong to the same row with the same Y. Have you any suggestion to do that?

Comment: You should add some notes on what you're trying to achieve. Do you just want to get a "net" based on those dots or are you tryign to get the intrinsic/extrinsic camera variables? Do you want to transform the whole image or get the camera's orientation?

Comment: No I want only order the center founded with findContours.

Answer (score 0):

How about picking your leftmost points as starting points. Then, for every point, find the point to the right with the closest vertical distance having the same (or every second time a different) color than the previous one? You could as well use edge detection to get the borders of the boxes, which would allow you to ensure that you don't cross these.